# Is it possible to run multiple sampling methods in caret package in the same training model (R)?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, random-forest, caret, resampling

I'm training a random forest model to predict a categorical outcome. Is there any way I can make the model apply four methods of sampling without having to write four separate codes (one for each sampling method)?

My code is as follows:

```
set.seed(17)
ctrl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, sampling = "down", classProbs = TRUE, savePredictions=TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
grid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(1:12))
m.rf = train(fast11 ~ ., data = fast11.inp.1, method = "rf", metric = "ROC", trControl=ctrl, tuneGrid=grid)
m.rf
```

I wanted to use "down, up, smote, rose" in the same code, instead of writing three identical codes just replacing "down" for "up", "rose" and "smote".

Answer (score 1):

Just looking into this myself. Have you tried adding a vector to the trainControl?

```
trainControl{
sampling = c("up", "down", "rose", "smote")
}
```

Otherwise you can change the trainControl sampling via:

```
trainControl$sampling <- "up"
```

And from there it should be simple enough to construct a loop.